# How to detect if text contain herf link

Tags: vue.js

I need to use vue to detect all links in the text like if i have text like this

text :
'hello mate check this link'

i want this text when it buffering in div it appear like this

'hello mate check this [link](https://link)'

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way:

HTML

```
<span v-html="formattedText"></span>
```

Script

```
  data() {
    return {
      text: 'Some kind of text with url www.google.com'
    }
  },
  computed: {
    formattedText() { 
      return this.linkify(this.text)
    }
  },
  methods: {
     linkify(inputText) {
    const pattern1 = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim;
    let text = inputText.replace(pattern1, '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>');

    const pattern2 = /(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;
    text = text.replace(pattern2, '$1<a href="http://$2" target="_blank">$2</a>');
    return text;
}
```

It should meet your expectations, you can also change $1 and $2 in `>$1|2</a>` to link.

Comment: this was an example , the idea is i want if someone add a link in a text when he submit it this link is viewed in a href

Comment: I have adjusted answer, now it should works as you want

Comment: why should I use a computed property when the input text is static? or it's for an input field?

Answer (score 0):

Well there are tons of libraries you could use to easily achieve this. But I personally would recommend [Anchorme.js](http://alexcorvi.github.io/anchorme.js/#getting-started) due to it's very small size. You can even customize the way the link will get handled when there are `#ids` & `@mentions` in text.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;


new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function() {
    return {
      text: `Library works with (http://www.google.com) or without (www.google.com) protocols in link. It works well on paths [www.github.io/something/something] and queries <wordpress.com/post.php?p=112> and even when query starts immediately after the TLDS "wordpress.com?p=112".`,
      convertedText: ""
    }
  },
  computed: {
    htmlText() {
      const converted = anchorme({
        input: this.text,
        // use some options
        options: {
          attributes: {
            target: "_blank",
            class: "detected"
          }
        },
        // and extensions
        extensions: [
          // an extension for hashtag search
          {
            test: /#(\w|_)+/gi,
            transform: string =>
              `<a href="https://a.b?s=${string.substr(1)}">${string}</a>`
          },
          // an extension for mentions
          {
            test: /@(\w|_)+/gi,
            transform: string =>
              `<a href="https://a.b/${string.substr(1)}">${string}</a>`
          }
        ]
      });
      return converted;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.htmlText {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githack.com/alexcorvi/anchorme.js/gh-pages/dist/browser/anchorme.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <textarea v-model="text" placeholder="enter text here" rows="3" cols="100">
  </textarea>
  <br/><br/>
  <div class="htmlText" v-html="htmlText"></div>
</div>
```